# ShuffleJS FIlters OR + AND at the same time

Tags: javascript, filter, shuffle

I was wondering if it is possible to have several "data-groups" at the same time and filter them like this:

`<div data-st='["1", "2", "3"]' data-nd='["4", "5", "6"]' data-rd='["7", "8", "9"]' />`

Get my all item where "data-st" includes either 1 **OR** 2 **AND** "data-nd=" includes either 4 **OR** 5 **AND** "data-rd" includes either 7 OR 8.

I have tried many things already, but I can not figure it out... :(

And to make it more complex... Can ST, ND and RD be dynamic?

The wanted result would be all elements matching:

`data-st == 1 || data-st == 2 && data-nd == 4 || data-nd == 5 && data-rd == 7 || data-rd == 8`

And with dynamic values...

`var values = { hello: [1,2,3], world: [4,5,6]}`

`<div data-hello='["1","2","3"]' data-world='["4","5","6"]' />`

---

```
<button data-group="genre" data-value="animation">Animation</button>

<button data-group="genre" data-value="comedy">Comedy</button>

<button data-group="genre" data-value="drama">Drama</button>

<button data-group="actor" data-value="John Doe">John Doe</button>

<button data-group="actor" data-value="Laura Smith">Laura Smith</button>


<ul>
  <li data-genre='["animation", "comedy"]' data-actor='["John Doe", "Laura Smith"]'>
    Black Panther
  </li>
  <li data-genre='["comedy"]' data-actor='["John Doe"]'>
    Spiderman
  </li>
  <li data-genre='["drama"]' data-actor='["John Doe"]'>
    Superman
  </li>
  <li data-genre='["animation"]' data-actor='["Laura Smith"]'>
    Batman
  </li>
</ul>
```

So when I click on "Animation + Comedy". I should see "Black Panther + Spiderman + Batman"
After that I click on "John Doe". I should see now only "Black Panther + Spiderman"

Because the genre is either animation *OR* comedy *AND* the actor is John Doe

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I think the OP wants to filter dom by that category..

Comment: What do you mean by "Can ST, ND and RD be dynamic?"

Comment: @ArupRakshit instead of data-st to use a key from an object instead eg.

`var x = { hello: [1,2,3], world: [4,5,6]}`

so the div should look like `<div data-hello='[1,2,3]' data-world=[4,5,6] />`

Comment: You said `"data-st" equals 1 OR 2`, but I see it is `data-st='["1", "2", "3"]'`.. Did you mean includes either 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yeap... sorry... data-st includes either 1 or 2

Comment: @ToniProducto I am didn't get the dynamic part. But I think if you make data-attrs names dynamic, then selecting them will be hard if you don't them at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all dom nodes first by the presence of `data-*` attributes. And then filter them by the condition.

```js
var domNodes = document.querySelectorAll('[' + 'data-nd' + ']', '[' + 'data-rd' + ']', '[' + 'data-st' + ']');

var result = Array.from(domNodes).filter(node => {
  var nd = JSON.parse(node.dataset["nd"]);
  var rd = JSON.parse(node.dataset["rd"]);
  var st = JSON.parse(node.dataset["st"]);

  return (st.includes("1") || nd.includes("2")) && (nd.includes("4") || rd.includes("5")) && (nd.includes("8") || rd.includes("7"))
});

console.log(result.length);
```

```html
<div data-st='["1", "2", "3"]' data-nd='["4", "5", "6"]' data-rd='["7", "8", "9"]' />
<div data-st='["1", "2", "3"]' data-nd='["7", "9", "6"]' data-rd='["7", "10", "9"]' />
<div data-st='["1", "5", "3"]' data-nd='["4", "5", "6"]' data-rd='["7", "8", "9"]' />
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It works, but... ca the values be dynamic as well. 

I mean the "1" in st.includes("1") for instance

Let me put it like this...

`<button data-group="st" data-id="1">1</button> <button data-group="st" data-id="2">2</button> <button data-group="nd" data-id="4">4</button>`

And once you click one of those buttons you filter the list based on all the active clicked buttons

Comment: I don't understand you. But if you have a look at this code I gave and understand, I think you can take it further, no? :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!! And I was already that far before asking and I can not come any further ;(

Do you think, you can a look at the last example I added to the description?

Comment: Ok. I didn't get what you meant there.. TBH :)

Comment: Sorry! ;) Dude you will save my day if you find out a way to do this!!!

Comment: You need to put together it very well, then I may give it a try. But right now, I am not getting what you want.. haha

Comment: please please please

Answer (score 0):

An here comes the answer.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input-1" data-group="genre" data-value="animation" />
<label for="input-1">Animation</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="input-2" data-group="genre" data-value="comedy" />
<label for="input-2">Comedy</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="input-3" data-group="genre" data-value="drama" />
<label for="input-3">Drama</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="input-4" data-group="actor" data-value="John Doe" />
<label for="input-4">John Doe</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="input-5" data-group="actor" data-value="Laura Smith" />
<label for="input-5">Laura Smith</label>

<ul class="my-shuffle-container">
  <li class="item" data-genre='["animation", "comedy"]' data-actor='["John Doe", "Laura Smith"]'>
    Panther
    <div class="sizer"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-genre='["comedy"]' data-actor='["John Doe"]'>
    Spiderman
    <div class="sizer"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-genre='["drama"]' data-actor='["John Doe"]'>
    Superman
    <div class="sizer"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-genre='["animation"]' data-actor='["Laura Smith"]'>
    Batman
    <div class="sizer"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...

```
var Shuffle = window.Shuffle
var ul = document.querySelector('.my-shuffle-container')
var sizer = ul.querySelector('.sizer')

var shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(ul, {
  itemSelector: '.item',
  sizer: sizer
});

var inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
var genres = []
var actors = []

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const group = input.getAttribute('data-group')
    const value = input.getAttribute('data-value')

        if (input.checked && group === 'genre') {
        genres.push(value)
    }

    if (!input.checked && group === 'genre') {  
      genres.splice(genres.indexOf(value, 1))
    }

    if (input.checked && group === 'actor') {
        actors.push(value)
    }

    if (!input.checked && group === 'actor') {  
      actors.splice(actors.indexOf(value, 1))
    }

    shuffleInstance.filter(element => {
      console.log(actors, genres)

      const dataGenre = element.getAttribute('data-genre')
      const dataActor = element.getAttribute('data-actor')

      if (genres.length > 0 && !(genres.some(genre => _.includes(JSON.parse(dataGenre), genre)))) {
        return false
      }

      if (actors.length > 0 && !(actors.some(actor => _.includes(JSON.parse(dataActor), actor)))) {
        return false
      }

      return true
    })
  })
})
```